# usb wifi dongle on ubuntu server, cannot install realtek driver RTL 8188cus

Tags: custom-installer, make

I got cheap Ebay wifi dongle from HongKong, Im trying to set it up on my ubuntu server.

Occasionally need to move server, so it cannot always be connected to router via lan.

Anyhow, usb wifi came with a driver cd. I uploaded files to my home directory and tried to run install script (RTL 8188cus): sudo bash install.sh

But I get error:

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/build M=/home/minime/RTL 8188cus/Linux/driver/rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1324.20110126  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-server'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `8188cus/Linux/driver/rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1324.20110126'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-server'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
Compile make driver error: 2, Please check error Mesg
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

There is another driver folder for linux called: RTL 81XX, which doesn't have install.sh at all! I tried to use make command, but I get:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Any help? this is first time I'm installing driver from source.

Im on Ubuntu 11.04 server.

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation N10 Family DMI Bridge [8086:a000] (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:a001] (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation NM10 Family LPC Controller [8086:27bc] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller [8086:27c0] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Device [1969:1083] (rev c0)
```

sudo lshw

```
description: Desktop Computer
    product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall64 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: AD525PV3
       vendor: ASRock
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: P1.20
          date: 04/01/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 448KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D525   @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D525   @ 1.80GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPUSocket
          size: 1800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 48KiB
             capacity: 48KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: c
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: ModulePartNumber00
             vendor: Manufacturer00
             physical id: 0
             serial: SerNum00
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: ModulePartNumber01
             vendor: Manufacturer01
             physical id: 1
             serial: SerNum01
             slot: DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: N10 Family DMI Bridge
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:41 memory:fea80000-feafffff ioport:dc00(size=8) memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fe900000-fe9fffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:fea78000-fea7bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:feb00000-febfffff ioport:80000000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: Atheros Communications
                vendor: Atheros Communications
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: c0
                serial: XX
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.99 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:42 memory:febc0000-febfffff ioport:ec00(size=128)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 ioport:d880(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:d800(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:d480(size=32)
        *-usb:3
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:d400(size=32)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:fea77c00-fea77fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: e2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: NM10 Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: N10/ICH7 Family SATA IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ff90(size=16) memory:80200000-802003ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD10TPVT-11U
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 01.0
                serial: WD-WXC1A80P0314
                size: 931GiB (1TB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00088c47
              *-volume:0
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /media/private
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 042daf2d-350c-4640-a76a-4554c9d98c59
                   size: 300GiB
                   capacity: 300GiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2011-11-06 11:05:03 filesystem=ext4 label=Private lastmountpoint=/media/private modified=2012-04-13 20:01:16 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,barrier=1,stripe=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-04-13 20:01:16 state=mounted
              *-volume:1
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   size: 625GiB
                   capacity: 625GiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume:0
                      description: Linux filesystem partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      logical name: /media/storage
                      capacity: 600GiB
                      configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,barrier=1,stripe=1,data=ordered state=mounted
                 *-logicalvolume:1
                      description: Linux filesystem partition
                      physical id: 6
                      logical name: /dev/sda6
                      logical name: /media/dropbox
                      capacity: 24GiB
                      configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,barrier=1,stripe=1,data=ordered state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   logical name: /media/www
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 9b0a27b4-05d8-40d5-bfc7-4aeba198db7b
                   size: 2570MiB
                   capacity: 2570MiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2011-11-06 11:05:11 filesystem=ext4 label=www lastmountpoint=/media/www modified=2012-04-15 11:31:12 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,barrier=1,stripe=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-04-15 11:31:12 state=mounted
              *-volume:3
                   description: Linux swap volume
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                   logical name: /dev/sda4
                   version: 1
                   serial: 6ed1130e-3aad-4fa6-890b-77e729121e3b
                   size: 4098MiB
                   capacity: 4098MiB
                   capabilities: primary nofs swap initialized
                   configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:400(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:4
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             size: 3864MiB (4051MB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: signature=000b4c55
           *-volume
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 33926e39-4685-4f63-b83c-f2a67824b69a
                size: 3862MiB
                capacity: 3862MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2011-10-11 14:03:46 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2012-03-19 11:47:29 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-04-15 11:31:11 state=mounted
```

**rfkill list all
Doesnt show anything!**

dmesg | grep -i firmware

```
[    0.715481] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [Firmware Bug]: TigerPoint LPC.BM_STS cleared
```

Comment: Before you go down the compilation route... the kernel should hopefully have this built it.  To confirm, we need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: I added some of the info, is it fine like this?

Comment: hi there - have a look at my wifi answer - need the lshw results, rfkill and any dmesg results as well.

Comment: I added all but dmesg it is too big. but I put it here: http://freetexthost.com/2uymwup1vh

Comment: hmmm - I may have missed this - but I dont see any evidence of your usb wifi actually plugged in - `sudo lshw -class network` should show all your network devices even if they are unclaimed by the kernel - and `lsusb` should show the USB device plugged in. N.B. `lspci` will only help with wifi boards plugged into the motherboard.

Comment: In fact lsusb shows it, this is it: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Comment: :( guess it is one of those questions, that never get resolved... maybe I should head over to ubuntu forums? thanks for help btw.

Comment: ok - looks like this is not in the natty kernel.  Have you install the linux headers + build essential?  The latest source code is from here - have you tried these? http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2742

Comment: I tried from realtek website, but had same problem... make couldn't find anything to make :) and the driver that was on CD had at least install.sh so, we are back to square one :))) why do I get that error while installing the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following on my Natty VM:

First install the defaults:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential 
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Now, download the source code and extract the compressed tar file:

> Linux Kernel 2.6.18~2.6.38 and Kernel 3.0.2
>
> Android 1.6~2.3 and 4.x
>     3.3.2_3192  2012/1/9    8322k

now cd to the folder that was extracted.

```
sudo su
. ./install.sh
```

choose the card type

The compilation completed successfully.

Comment: wait I dont get it, should I change kernel?

Comment: ? no - that is the reference of the source code - apparently it can be used for all kernels between v2.6.18 and 2.6.38 (i.e. Natty).

Comment: well I get the same msg, first two commands did nothing...

Comment: Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/build M=/home/minime/RTL 8188cus/Linux/driver/rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1324.20110126  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-server'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `8188cus/Linux/driver/rtl8192CU_linux_v2.0.1324.20110126'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-server'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
Compile make driver error: 2, Please check error Mesg